# what does breakpoint mean on bootstrap spacing?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

According to the bootstrap 4 docs

> The classes are named using the format {property}{sides}-{size} for xs and {property}{sides}-{breakpoint}-{size} for sm, md, lg, and xl.

I would like to apply margin top effect on a "col-md-12" class but not sure what the term breakpoint mean and how do i actually implement it.

Comment: it means when the property will apply so `mb-sm-4` will add a bottom margin starting from the `sm` breakpoint and upper (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/grid/#grid-options)

Comment: "Less than 728px, apply this style. More than 728px, apply this style". In this case, 728px is a breakpoint, because in that point the continuity with the old style "breaks" and the new style is applied. But I don't know bootstrap enough to answer your question